# Getting if ($max > 0 && $request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH') > $max) {throw new PostTooLargeException;} exception

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I try to upload a really big > 30MB image, I get this exception:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $max = $this->getPostMaxSize();
 
        if ($max > 0 && $request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH') > $max) {
            throw new PostTooLargeException;
        }
 
        return $next($request);
    }
```

I've not set a validator for max image size in my ImagesController where my `uploadImage()` function is and I've set `upload_max_filesize = 100M`. This is why I have no clue why is this exception being thrown.

Comment: What is the maximum upload set to in your `php.ini`?

Comment: My max upload set in php.ini is 100M

Comment: What about your `post_max_size`? Try setting that to something a little larger than your `upload_max_filesize`, such as `post_max_size = 125M`.

Comment: Ok I set it to 125M and now I get "website name is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500" when I try to upload it.

Answer (score 1):

In the `php.ini` file set `post_max_size =`and `upload_max_filesize =` your maximum file size eg; `post_max_size = 126MB`

This solved my problem and I hope it helps.